# CreateToolhelp32Snapshot: INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE (ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY)

Tags: c++, windows, snapshot

This code is running in a 64-bit application. The target application is 32-bit.

Every time I run this code, `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` and then `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY`. So it skips the loop and returns false.

```
BOOL HookInjector::InjectIntoProcess(DWORD pID)
{
    //Get Handle to Remote Process
    HANDLE Proc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);
    ....
    //Check to see if 64-bit or 32-bit application
    IsWow64Process(Proc, &isWow64);
    size_t szCurProc = sizeof(void*); //returns 8
    if (isWow64)
    {
        __debugbreak();
        //Get list of all Modules associated with the Process
        HANDLE hProc32Module;
        do {
            hProc32Module = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, pID);
        }
        while ((hProc32Module == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) && (GetLastError() == ERROR_BAD_LENGTH));

    if (hProc32Module == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        __debugbreak();
        DWORD err = GetLastError(); //just to see the error code which is 0x12b
        return false;
    }

        //Find the module for Kernel.dll and get the base address of it
        MODULEENTRY32 entryModule;
        entryModule.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);
        BOOL isGetModuleSuccess = Module32First(hProc32Module, &entryModule);
        DWORD errEndofList = GetLastError();
        BOOL isSuccessful = false;
        while (errEndofList != ERROR_NO_MORE_FILES && isGetModuleSuccess)
        {
            if (_tcscmp(entryModule.szModule, KERNEL32_DLL)){
                isSuccessful = true;
                break;
            }
            isGetModuleSuccess = Module32Next(hProc32Module, &entryModule);
            errEndofList = GetLastError();
        }

        if (!isSuccessful)
        {
            __debugbreak();
            CloseHandle(hProc32Module);
            return false;
        }

        //Get handle for Kernel.dll module
        hKernel32 = entryModule.hModule;
        CloseHandle(hProc32Module);
    }
    else
    {
        ....
```

Comment: Do you know which function call yields the error? We certainly don't. All your error checking is wrong so you probably don't know either. You have to check return values. You don't. If the return value indicates failure, and the docs say last error is valid, then call `GetLastError`. I urge you to fix the error checking, and then ask again.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Sry, bout that. And yes I do know which function yields the error.

    hProc32Module = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, pID);

hProc32Module shouldn't be INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE after this line. But it is, so that means an error occured because CreateToolhelp32Snapshot only returns the handle or INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE if an error occurs.

Comment: Well, in that case I guess you're in the best position to work on this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: ...Ehhh sry if I made you angry or something, I just hit enter before I finished my comment. I'll update the post and provide more details

Comment: Here is an example I've made in C#.  It uses system library calls so you should be able to port it to C++ almost line by line.  Or you can try it out for yourself from a C# test application.  https://gist.github.com/ultratrunks/63008d0aafe3c7aec68b  Its got all the proper error checking and such. Just start at the InjectDll() routine.  If you compile it from x64 you can inject both x64 and x86 processes as long ans you provide it with an appropriately compiled injection dll.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682489.aspx), `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` only fails with `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` when `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` is called by a 32bit process trying to access a 64bit process:

> If the specified process is a 64-bit process and **the caller is a 32-bit process**, this function fails and the last error code is ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY (299).

Make sure your app really is compiled for 64bit to begin with.  `TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32` only makes sense to use when `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()` is being called in a 64bit process:

> TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32
>   0x00000010
>   Includes all 32-bit modules of the process specified in th32ProcessID in the snapshot **when called from a 64-bit process**.

You are also not taking into account that `GetLastError()` is only updated when API functions fail, unless documented otherwise.  Your loops are assuming that `GetLastError()` is updated after every API call, that is simply not true.

Try something more like this instead:

```
BOOL HookInjector::InjectIntoProcess(DWORD pID)
{
    //Get Handle to Remote Process
    HANDLE Proc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);
    ....

    DWORD dwFlag;
    #ifdef _WIN64
    //Check if Remote Process is a 32-bit application
    BOOL isWow64 = FALSE;
    IsWow64Process(Proc, &isWow64);
    if (!isWow64) return false;
    // TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32 includes 32bit modules when used by a 64bit process...
    dwFlag = TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32;
    #else
    // TH32CS_SNAPMODULE includes 32bit modules when used by a 32bit process...
    dwFlag = TH32CS_SNAPMODULE;
    #endif

    __debugbreak();

    //Get list of all Modules associated with the Process

    HANDLE hProc32Module;
    do {
        hProc32Module = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(dwFlag, pID);
    }
    while ((hProc32Module == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) && (GetLastError() == ERROR_BAD_LENGTH));

    if (hProc32Module == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        __debugbreak();
        return false;
    }

    //Find the module for Kernel.dll and get the base address of it

    hKernel32 = NULL;

    MODULEENTRY32 entryModule = {0};
    entryModule.dwSize = sizeof(MODULEENTRY32);

    BOOL isGetModuleSuccess = Module32First(hProc32Module, &entryModule);
    while (isGetModuleSuccess) {
        if (_tcscmp(entryModule.szModule, KERNEL32_DLL)) {
            hKernel32 = entryModule.hModule;
            break;
        }
        isGetModuleSuccess = Module32Next(hProc32Module, &entryModule);
    }

    if (!hKernel32) {
        __debugbreak();
        CloseHandle(hProc32Module);
        return false;
    }

    CloseHandle(hProc32Module);

    ....
}
```

Comment: The reason I'm sure that my app is 64bit is because I was able to load the 64bit dll file into 64bit processes (my hooks worked). That's why I'm completely dumbfounded as to why it returns ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY and INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE before when I run this application on a 32-bit process.

Comment: Just because you can load a 64bit DLL into other 64bit processes does not mean the calling process is 64bit. You have to make sure you are compiling the code for a 64bit platform. Easiest way to verify that is to check `sizeof(void*)` to see if it is 4 (32bit) or 8 (64bit), or call `IsWow64Process()` on the calling process.

Comment: sizeof(void*) returns me 8 implying 64-bit calling process. I also made the changes you told me, except I added a DWORD err = GetLastError() in the if (hProc32Module == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) statement. I get the err 0x12b which is ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY after checking that hProc32Module is indeed INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE.

Comment: I think your statement "CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() cannot fail with ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY when called by a 64bit process" is incorrect.  I've faced a similar problem and I'm calling from a 64bit application.  The application has an aggressive polling loop for detecting new processes starting, thus I'm calling the method during the first few milliseconds of the applications life. It appears that sometimes the snapshot data just isn't ready yet.  My remedy for the problem was to wait a second when I get this error, and try again. You can definitely get this error from 64bit applications.

Comment: Then that is not documented behavior. The documentation only states that `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` happens when a 32bit process tries to access a 64bit process.  In any case, why are you *polling* for process creation at all, instead of using WMI or ETW events to let Windows *notify* you when a new process is created?

Comment: Same problem here. 64 bits process, checked with dumpbin. CreateToolhelp32Snapshot returns INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE and GetLastError yields 299 (ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY). I'm running windows 10, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> According to the documentation, CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() *only* fails with ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY when CreateToolhelp32Snapshot() is called by a 32bit process trying to access a 64bit process:
>
> > If the specified process is a 64-bit process and the caller is a 32-bit process, this function fails and the last error code is ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY (299).

This is plain wrong as you could have deduced from the excerpt you posted. Where does it say it ONLY fails with `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY (299)` when the caller is 32bit trying to access 64bit? It doesn't.

If the documentation would be complete, which it is not, then you would be right to assume that the stated behaviour is the only way to generate an `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` error code. Sadly the documentation is not complete.

For example if you start a process with the `CREATE_SUSPENDED` flag the `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` API will set the error code to `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` when queried for modules regardless of the bitness of the host or target application. The reason it fails is because the DLLs aren't loaded until after the main thread is resumed and therefore the `PebLdr` pointer in the `PEB` structure is `NULL`.

Basically anything which prevents read of process memory (missing address in `PEB`, unmapped segment, etc.) can cause `ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY` as its description states:

```
ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY 299 (0x12B)
Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.
```